# Geolocation, service and local notifications

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to make my first system application for Android related to geolocation and local notifications.
I imagine it like this... There is basic activity `MainActivity`. After start it launches a service `TestService` which in case of change of coordinates sends them on the server, and in reply receives some message which will displayed as the local notification.
And I have some problems.

1. If I close the application (using task manager) then the service will stop, so after change of coordinates nothing happens.
   What I need do that service work all the time? Or it's impossible?
2. After activation of the local notification it launches `NotifyActivity` which shows detailed information. There I click `buttonDelete` - it will close `NotifyActivity` and start `MainActivity`. But if after that I switch to the OS screen (using `Back` button) and back (using task manager) then instead of 'MainActivity' will be again displayed 'NotifyActivity'.
   Why it occurs and how to avoid it?

MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "LocationTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate {
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(TestService)));
            button.Text = "Started";
        };
    }
}
```

Geolocation service

```
[Service]
public class TestService : Service, ILocationListener
{
    // Start service
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        locManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        locationCriteria = new Criteria();

        locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse;
        locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.Low;

        string locationProvider = locManager.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);

        // Preferences.MinTime, for example, 60 (seconds)
        // Preferences.MinDist, for example, 100 (meters)
        locManager.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, Preferences.MinTime * 1000, Preferences.MinDist, this);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        // Send coordinates to the server, receive a response, and show local notification
        var msg = new ReceivedMessage(counter++, "Test Title", loc.ToString());
        ShowNotification(msg);
    }

    // show local notification
    void ShowNotification(ReceivedMessage msg)
    {
        var myContainer = new Bundle();
        myContainer.PutLong("msg_id", Convert.ToInt64(msg.Id));
        myContainer.PutStringArray("msg_data", new [] { msg.Title, msg.Text });
        var resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotifyActivity));
        resultIntent.PutExtras(myContainer);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotifyActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(Convert.ToInt32(msg.Id), PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(msg.Title)
            .SetContentText(msg.Text)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

        var nm = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        nm.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(msg.Id), builder.Build());
    }

}
```

local notifications

```
[Activity(Label = "NotifyActivity")]            
public class NotifyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NotifyActivity);

        var msg_id = Intent.Extras.GetLong("msg_id");
        var msg_data = Intent.Extras.GetStringArray("msg_data");

        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textTitle).Text = msg_data[0];
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textDescription).Text = msg_data[1];

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonDelete).Click += delegate {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            Finish();
        };
    }
}
```

Example project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sl49l1o2jj50829/Location_Test.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity add this code. This method will solve your second problem (bus still I don't know how to solve issue with application title in the list of recent apps).

```
public override bool OnKeyDown (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
        MoveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown (keyCode, e);
}
```

Beeing hones activities in Android have a lot of pitfalls. Hence my suggestion is to launch MainActivity from service and then launch NotifyAcitivity. Then you can launch MainActivity again (in this case you'll need to set LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop for MainActivity).

For the first problem - have you tried defining `[Service (Process = ":remote")]` instead of `[Service]`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with xamarin, but I can try to answer the questions as they relate generally to Android.

**Question 1**

When you close your app through the task manager, you are doing more than simply closing the app - you are killing the entire process. Although you can't control your users' behavior, generally this is not the way that an Android user is supposed to stop an app. The "correct" way to close an app is to simply back out of it, which does not destroy the process, and keeps your Service running in the background.

So to answer your question, I don't think there's anything you can do to get around this situation where a user forcefully kills your app's process. However, I don't think you need to worry about this edge case because under normal circumstances, your app's process won't be killed until the system deems it's ok or absolutely needs it. So the service should continue running if the app is closed in a normal way. The docs say:

> the system will keep the service running as long as either it is
>   started or there are one or more connections to it with the
>   Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag. Once neither of these situations hold,
>   the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is
>   effectively terminated.

So your service will be OK. Generally, your app is not expected to handle cases where its process is forcefully killed.

[More information about Processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes)

[More information about the Service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)

**Question 2**

I am not exactly sure what's going on here. However, looking at your linked project, I notice that your `AndroidManifest.xml` file is barely filled out. My suspicion is that without this file, the android system doesn't know how to initialize your backstack, and it doesn't know which of your activities is the MAIN and LAUNCHER activity.

You should declare your activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and in it you should specify that `MainActivity` is your MAIN and LAUNCHER activity, and that it is a parent of `NotifyActivity`. This way the system will know to open `MainActivity` when the app is started, and it'll know to return to it when you hit "back" from `NotifyActivity`. Something like this:

```
<application android:label="LocationTest" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter> 
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="NotifyActivity" 
        android:parentActivityName="MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

[More information about how to use your Android Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Hopefully that helps you solve your problems!

Comment: I think you are somewhat wrong on both accounts. First, I don't think the OP is talking about force closing the process, I think they are referring to swiping the app from the recent app list, which should only close and remove that task stack, not stop the whole process. Second, in xamarin the activities are declared using attributes on the activity classes themselves. They are then later (at compile time) put into the manifest automatically.